# Is there a way to use wxPython's GIFAnimationCtrl with images generated with img2py?

Tags: wxpython

Is there a way to use wxPython's [GIFAnimationCtrl](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.animate.GIFAnimationCtrl-class.html) (which requires a filename, not a file) with images generated with [img2py](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.tools.img2py-module.html)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about PyEmbeddedImage and img2py.py, but here is a way I found to embed animation into python source code.

```
gif_img_base64 = (
  "R0lGODlhEAAQAPQAAP///wAAAPDw8IqKiuDg4EZGRnp6egAAAFhYWCQkJKysrL"
  "6+vhQUFJycnAQEBDY2NmhoaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
  ...
  "PAqFgYy02xkSaLEMV34tELyRYNEsCQyHlvWkGCzsPgMCEAY7Cg04Uk48LAsDhR"
  "A8MVQPEF0GAgqYYwSRlycNcWskCkApIyEAOwAAAAAAAAAAAA=="
  )

a = wx.animate.GIFAnimationCtrl(self, -1, '') # The control

a2 = wx.animate.Animation() # The data
data = base64.b64decode(gif_img_base64)
a2.Load(cStringIO.StringIO(data))
a.SetAnimation(a2) # Bind the data and the control

a.GetPlayer().UseBackgroundColour(True)
a.Play()
```

The variable gif_img_base64 is base64-encoded content of a GIF file with animation. A helper program to create the code:

```
import sys, base64
data = sys.stdin.read()
s = base64.b64encode(data)
print 'gif_img_base64 = ('
while s:
  print '  "' + s[:62] + '"'
  s = s[62:]
print '  )'
```